# How to get all the <li> after table tag 1 and table tag 2 with python?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hello there i want to parse or **scrape** data from this sites.

[http://mis.pamsimas.org/2014/result_table.php?apl=undefined&thn=2014&type=REG|ALL&dan=ALL&mod=2.1.2.1|Pemetaan%20Sosial|t_imas_peta_sosial|des||t_2121_peta_sosial&leve=&grop=](http://mis.pamsimas.org/2014/result_table.php?apl=undefined&thn=2014&type=REG%7CALL&dan=ALL&mod=2.1.2.1%7CPemetaan%20Sosial%7Ct_imas_peta_sosial%7Cdes%7C%7Ct_2121_peta_sosial&leve=&grop=)

my question by that site how to get only data from "18  Nusa Tenggara Timur" to "145    Sabu Raijua"

thanks for you respond im trying using find_all and else but i got it wrong.

```
import bs4
import request

html = request.get(link)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
        soup.prettify()
        ul = soup.find("ul", id="sitemap")
        for li in ul.find_all('table'):
            if "Jawa Timur" in li.text.strip():
                print(li.nextSibling())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you want output formatted. Initially you can select just the relevant tables as follows. Requires bs4 4.7.1+ as uses :contains and :has for filtering.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('http://mis.pamsimas.org/2014/result_table.php?apl=undefined&thn=2014&type=REG|ALL&dan=ALL&mod=2.1.2.1|Pemetaan%20Sosial|t_imas_peta_sosial|des||t_2121_peta_sosial&leve=&grop=')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

for table in soup.select('table:has(th:contains("Nusa Tenggara Timur")), table:has(th:contains("Nusa Tenggara Timur")) ~ li:not(table:has(th:contains("Kalimantan Barat")) ~ li)'):
    print(pd.read_html(str(table)))
```

---

If you want output similar to your image in comments then use the following (you will need to assign customer headers with df.columns)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('http://mis.pamsimas.org/2014/result_table.php?apl=undefined&thn=2014&type=REG|ALL&dan=ALL&mod=2.1.2.1|Pemetaan%20Sosial|t_imas_peta_sosial|des||t_2121_peta_sosial&leve=&grop=')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
trs = soup.select('tr:contains("Nasional"), table:has(th:contains("Nusa Tenggara Timur")) tr, table:has(th:contains("Nusa Tenggara Timur")) ~ li:not(table:has(th:contains("Kalimantan Barat")) ~ li) tr')
results = []

for tr in trs:
    row = [i.text.replace('\xa0 ','') if i.img is None else 'tick' for i in tr.select('th,td:not([title])')]
    if len(row) > 15:
        row = row[1:-1]
    results.append(row)
df = pd.DataFrame(results)
print(df)
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Data.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig',index = False )
```

---

I have replaced the images of ticks with the word `tick` in output. Sample of output (some rows hidden):

[image]

---

**Reading:**

1. [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

Comment: How to trabsfer it in pd.Dataframe with 13 Col only..? I still confused to do that. Thanks anyway

Comment: Can you post a link to an image of how you want the first two rows to look? Then I will update for you.  If you look at the page there are  "merged cells" as you have a header row then slightly indented sub rows (for when you expand the plus).

Comment: wow greats thanks so much dude. its rock and roll. just like i need. now i ll try to just get several column.

btw about this command 'trs = soup.select('tr:contains("Nasional"), table:has(th:contains("Nusa Tenggara Timur")) tr, table:has(th:contains("Nusa Tenggara Timur")) ~ li:not(table:has(th:contains("Kalimantan Barat")) ~ li) tr')' whats its mean..? could u give some ref about this so i can more understand it. Thanks.

Comment: I have added a reading link on CSS selectors to the question for you